# how to register winform client app in azure app registration as desktop app using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to write powershell script for registering winform client app in azure app registration. I want to register as Mobile Desktop app as below using powershell.

[image]

Which azure tools should I use to create from powershell?

Thanks

Comment: Could you confirm whether your requirement is to create azure ad app registration with redirect URI in `Mobile and desktop application` via PowerShell?

Comment: Hi @Sridevi, yes this is my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of below **Az** PowerShell command to register application with redirect URI in `Mobile and desktop application` platform:

```
New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "app_name" -PublicClientRedirectUri "http://localhost"
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where app registration created successfully with **redirect URI** in `Mobile and desktop application` platform like this:

[image]